# If app crashes or closed from task manager then that time i want to hit api

Tags: android, api, service

I have created a service and called this service class from BaseActivity.

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, UserAvailabilityService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);

public class UserAvailabilityService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = UserAvailabilityService.class.getSimpleName();
    boolean isChecked = false;
    boolean isUserAvailable = false;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");
        isChecked = getAvailableStatusFromFref();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand()");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.i(TAG, "onTaskRemoved()");
        if(isChecked) {
            //Hit a api
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
    }
    }
```

If app crashes or closed from task manager then that time i want to hit api.

Right Now, When i am swipping the app from background this onTaskRemoved method is calling. and i am hitting the api.

But when i am closing the same app from task manager (Setting->Apps->App name->Force Stop) then this onTaskRemoved method is not calling.

Any idea,please let me know.

Comment: @Jonas Any events for killing apps from task manager? can i handle the above scenerio through service and receiver or any events in android?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.  You cannot tell from within an app whether the app will be terminated.  You could watch for termination from a second app, but at any time the first can be closed without notice.  Not to mention the variety of ways that both apps could be shut down (for example, they could just pull the battery).  You should never write code that requires you to do something on shutdown, because it will never be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is calling isFinishing() which checks if it is being destroyed from you onPause() method

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(isFinishing){
        callApi();
    }
}
```

Comment: I called this method from BaseActivity class. But didn't work.If any other solution then plz let me know.

Comment: provide more details and code because i always use this and works fine

Comment: There are two conditions where I can killed/closed the app.

Condition 1:- 
We can swipe the app from background and close the running app.
Running App -> click on home button -> app went into background -> right swipe the app-> killed the app.
(I can do this condition through service and api will in onTaskRemoved method)
Condition 2:-
We can close the app from this way.
Phone Setting -> Apps -> select app -> Click on force Stop button                         (Do u have any suggestion for condition 2 )

Comment: all i can think about is calling the api from the onDestroy method otherwise i will tell you it is not possible and you should check it on the onPause method